# Web Crawlers are reversing query parameters and path when scraping pages

Tags: angularjs, web-crawler, prerender

We have an AngularJS based web application that currently uses hashbang urls, such as:

```
www.example.com/#!/item?id=1.
```

For crawling purposes, we use the prerender.io service to render/cache pages. For our meta tags (og, twitter specifically) we use an angular library called angular-view-head.  Until around a month ago, this was all working beautifully, and our pages were both searchable and sharable as expected.

Currently, when scraping pages on our site, crawlers appear to be switching the path for the query strings.  For example,

```
www.somesite.com/#!/item?id=1
```

becomes

```
www.somesite.com/?id=1#!/item
```

Which, as you might suspect, returns a 404 always.

After some checking, this seems to have started sometime around the 7th of February.  We haven't changed anything with our prerender setup nor our URL schema.  I've checked google webmaster tools, and see many 404s for urls such as these.

I haven't had any luck in my research over the last few days finding any similar issues.

Has anyone faced something similar with this style of setup?  Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Either of those URLs are technically valid and the query string before the hash is just as correct, but it looks like AngularJS does see them as different when you are using the # in the URL. You'd almost have to detect those URLs and redirect them to put the query string after the hash. Are you able to switch to html5 push state?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  We'll look into the remapping.  We would like to avoid moving to push state for the time being, but it's an option if unavoidable.  Has something recently caused the switch?  Is this something on the prerender side, or on the crawlers?

Comment: We have always done our URLs the same way so I don't think this would be a Prerender issue. Feel free to send us an email at support@prerender.io if you need any help looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this question, we solved this by moving to HTML5 push-state navigation.